# .mdb form information to pandas dataframe using pyodbc

Tags: python, pandas, ms-access, pyodbc

I've got a form in a ms access database that when viewed in Datasheet view looks exactly like a table I'd like to work with in pandas to manipulate. Problem is, pyodbc can't handle forms like they can tables to make this easy (at least I'm not aware of how). Does anyone know how to do this, or where documentation is related to this?

Comment: Datasheets are forms that have record sources that point either to a table or query. Simply use that table/query in pyodbc.

Comment: @Parfait I believe I found the query, thanks for pointing out the clarification. How would you enter this into pyodbc/python for formatting purposes though? Nothing I run will take it

Comment: That is no SQL query. Open form in design view and under *Data* tab of properties, find *RecordSource* which can be an SQL query, a named table, or named query. This is what you use for pyodbc's `cur.execute(<SQL QUERY>)`.

Comment: Ok, making more sense. Thank you!

Comment: @Parfait The query is working correctly now, thank you for the help. The last step I'm trying to do (as opposed to loading the data into Pandas as stated above) it would just be easier to load the queried data into a report who's format exists already (we do this manually with a button, which is what I'm trying to automate) do yo now how or is it possible to transfer the query into the report and print it within pyodbc? (a normal desktop printer)

Comment: Why not do that in MS Access? Why do you need pyodbc?

Comment: I have this long sequence of stuff that's done manually, scanning and retiteling documents, moving them to folders, finding cell values in an xlsx spreadsheet, copying files and releasing them to another server folder etc. Printing out two records that were filtered through the Access DB is yet another of these tasks. I've automated most of them with Python already, it would be really nice to not have to go into this DB and do this step manually. the DB is a mess and it's actually th most time consuming of the steps. It's all done in this one script I'm writing, I'd like this to be included

Comment: I have one more pyodbc question for you since you know your stuff. Can you set variables dynamically in the query? For instance `SELECT * WHERE ProgramNo = O0001"` where the 'O0001' would not be O0001 but a variable loaded from an earlier point in the script?

Comment: @Parfait never mind on the last question, solved it with fetchall: `cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM ToolingData WHERE ProgramNo = ?", (programNumber))
programTooling = pd.DataFrame.from_records(cursor.fetchall(),
                               columns = [desc[0] for desc in cursor.description])`